# Python Parse Text Across Multiple Lines

Tags: python

I have a text file that I need to process where the data is formatted in a way like this:

```
<emptyline> 
Recno:: 0
URL:: http://domain1.com/

ParseText::
Home - 360° Virtualisi...

Recno:: 1
URL:: http://domain2.com/

ParseText:: 
IIS Windows Server

Recno:: 2 
URL:: http://domain3.com/

ParseText::
ArrowECS Israel. Grow . ...

...
```

The good news is that the format is consistent, where a record always

1. empty line
2. start with record number
3. the second line is the URL
4. then an empty line,
5. ParseText:: line,
6. text line and

First, I really don't know if this is any type of standard like XML, JSON...

Second, if so, how can I transform this into a json? it is not that straightforward and I have to write a customized parser.

Answer (score 0):

You can just read lines one by one and add entries to a list:

```
records = []
with open("filename") as f:
    while True:
        if f.readline() == '': break # break if file is empty
        recno = f.readline().split(":: ")[1]
        url = f.readline().split(":: ")[1]
        f.readline()
        f.readline() # ParseText:: 
        parsetext = f.readline()
        records.append({
            "url": url,
            "recno": recno,
            "parsetext": parsetext,
            })
```

If you need that as JSON, you can encode it with `json.dumps`:

```
import json
print(json.dumps(records))
```

This should work, as long as the file is exactly like you described.